# Unable to login as user using GNOME session

Tags: gnome, 14.04, login, dbus

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 with GNOME3 Team's GNOME3-Staging PPA and now unable to login (as user) because of an issue about DBus. I know that because trying `sudo restart dbus` takes forever. However, login as root (from Ctrl-Alt F1 console, I have enabled root account) followed by `startx /usr/bin/gnome-shell` works at least partially. GNOME Terminal would not work because it could not register itself via (the missing) session bus.
My display manager is GDM 3.12. My `init` daemon is `Upstart`, however trying `SystemD` gives the same failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved afted upgrading to 13.10 alpha and transistioning to systemd.